# Show the current time of the video, instead of the remaining time on videojs

Tags: time, video.js

I use [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/), a HTML5 video player

By default it displays the remaining time (countdown) instead of the normal current time (like youtube)

Any ideas how to "fix" it? You can see a live example at [their official website](http://videojs.com/)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**For other people that search for a solution...**

**All timers exist** on the player but by default the `current-time`, `time-divider` and the `duration` info **are hidden** with `display: none;`.

So the only thing we have to do is **hide the `remaining-time`** and **show the `time-control`** which includes the `current-time`, `time-divider` and the `duration`.

The solution in **CSS code** that should work with your player:

```
.video-js .vjs-time-control {
    display: block;
}
.video-js .vjs-remaining-time {
    display: none;
}
```

[image: player-with-time-control]

The documentation does not explain this, or to be precise it fails to explain it when it explains how to customize your player with CSS.

---

Fast html code snippet:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .video-js .vjs-time-control{display: block;}
    .video-js .vjs-remaining-time{display: none;}
</style>
```

Comment: For me, instead of changing `.vjs-time-control`, I changed `.vjs-current-time`, which solved my problem

Comment: It displays vjs-time-control however, there is no time on it: "/"

Comment: I can not believe it that we have to hack the DOM elements visibility to do this :/

Answer (score 6):

easy way is change default ControlBar.prototype.options

```
ControlBar.prototype.options_ = {
  children: ['playToggle', 'volumePanel', 'currentTimeDisplay', 'timeDivider', 'durationDisplay', 'progressControl', 'liveDisplay', 'remainingTimeDisplay', 'customControlSpacer', 'playbackRateMenuButton', 'chaptersButton', 'descriptionsButton', 'subsCapsButton', 'audioTrackButton', 'fullscreenToggle']
};
```

change to

```
ControlBar.prototype.options_ = {
  loadEvent: 'play',
  children: ['playToggle', 'volumeMenuButton', 'currentTimeDisplay', 'progressControl', 'liveDisplay', 'durationDisplay', 'customControlSpacer', 'playbackRateMenuButton', 'chaptersButton', 'subtitlesButton', 'captionsButton', 'fullscreenToggle']
};
```

final display time control

```
<style type="text/css">
    .video-js .vjs-time-control{display:block;}
</style>
```

result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vvxm.png

Comment: new versions can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727017/how-to-change-the-position-of-videojs-control-bar-elements-order