# How to change the position of videojs Control bar elements order

Tags: javascript, css, video.js

I am using the video.js player for my website. I want to change the position of control bar elements.

Presently, it shows play/pause, volume, progress bar and full screen.

How can I able to change order?

I have my code below:

```
var videojs = videojs('video-player', {
    techOrder:  ["youtube", "html5"],
    preload: 'auto',
    controls: true,
    autoplay: true,
    fluid: true,
    controlBar: {
        CurrentTimeDisplay: true,
        TimeDivider: true,
        DurationDisplay: true
    },
    plugins: {
        videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
            default: 'high',
            dynamicLabel: true
        }
    }
}).ready(function() {
    var player = this;
   ......
```

Comment: Take a look at these questions, the answers in those might help [How to change button order in video.js (5.0.0-rc52)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081559/how-to-change-button-order-in-video-js-5-0-0-rc52) and [move item control bar videojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077682/move-item-control-bar-videojs)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I could able resolve by making changes as below:

```
    var videojs = videojs('video-player', {
    techOrder:  ["youtube", "html5"],
    preload: 'auto',
    controls: video.player.controls,
    autoplay: video.player.autoplay,
    fluid: true,
    controlBar: {
        children: [
            "playToggle",
            "volumeMenuButton",
            "durationDisplay",
            "timeDivider",
            "currentTimeDisplay",
            "progressControl",
            "remainingTimeDisplay",
            "fullscreenToggle"
        ]
    },
    plugins: {
        videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
            default: 'high',
            dynamicLabel: true
        }
    }
}).ready(function() {
    var player = this;
```

I thought it will help somebody in future.

Taken idea from [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/dojubuvixi/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: greatly! but why there must be using css?

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version (v7.15.4), some of Sankar's options listed below have changed. After some hunting around I was able to find a list here on the [video.js](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-components.html#specific-component-details) website under the Default Component Tree.

Also when enabling them, make sure that if you have a theme that it doesn't hide some of the options.