# How do I move the videojs control bar out of the video area or duplicate a videojs control bar?

Tags: javascript, frontend, video.js

I used a canvas element to pixelate a video by covering it on the video. But the canvas element will cover the control bar. So is there a way to move the control bar out of the video area or hide the original one and duplicate a new videojs control bar?

[image: The pixelate canvas cover on the video]

[control bar in the video area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZykMJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZykMJ.png)

By the way, is this the best practice to pixelate a video in front end?

[image: the canvas element I used to cover the whole video]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assign the property pointer-events: none to the canvas so the merge will be seamless.

```html
<canvas style="pointer-events:none">...
```

This way, your canvas will be just a filter, with no way of intercepting a click or anything else.

For the other question. No forcibly best practice as it's a bit subjective, however, for more complex effects, it is a used technic.

---

EDIT: There's an example here to move a custom control bar.
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2857

---

I did some quick tests. You can move the control bar with CSS

```
.vjs-control-bar
{
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Although I can click the button through the canvas with `style="pointer-events:none"`, but I still can not see the buttons.

Comment: Can you see the buttons without the canvas?

Comment: Yes, maybe I misunderstood the buttons? I mean the control bar buttons.

Comment: You should be able to see them.  There's an example here for videoJs setup:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727017/how-to-change-the-position-of-videojs-control-bar-elements-order
And here, to position the control bar:
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2857
Note that if it does not help, you could post more code examples. But that should do it.

---
EDIT: You can also hide the videojs control bar and use custom buttons.

Comment: You can see the picture above. I used a canvas element to cover the video.

Comment: As far as I can see from the links, the two links only discuss the order of the custom buttons in the control bar. And do you mean I should add my own extra buttons outside of the videojs after hiding the videojs control bar?

Comment: Yes. If you find it too complicated, I would hide the current buttons and define some custom ones. Unfortunately, I can't see your code, so I am unsure what's challenging. 
Note that we need to go to a Stackoverflow chat to discuss more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250941/discussion-between-patrice-thimothee-and-runtimeerrorz).